# Using variables in reStructuredText

Tags: wiki, restructuredtext

I'm writing a long HOWTO in reStructuredText format and wondering if there's a way to let user specify values for a couple variables (hostname, ip address) at the top so the rest of the document would be filled with those automatically?

Answer (score 10):

Like me, you are probably looking for [substitution](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#substitution-definitions). At the bottom of the section you'll find how to replace text.

> **Substitution Definitions**
>
> Doctree element: substitution_definition.
>
> Substitution definitions are indicated by an explicit markup start
>   (".. ") followed by a vertical bar, the substitution text, another
>   vertical bar, whitespace, and the definition block. Substitution text
>   may not begin or end with whitespace. A substitution definition block
>   contains an embedded inline-compatible directive (without the leading
>   ".. "), such as "image" or "replace".

Specifically about text replacement:

> **Replacement text**
>
> The substitution mechanism may be used for simple macro substitution. This may be appropriate when the replacement text is
>   repeated many times throughout one or more documents, especially if it
>   may need to change later. A short example is unavoidably contrived:
>
> ```
> |RST|_ is a little annoying to type over and over, especially
> when writing about |RST| itself, and spelling out the
> bicapitalized word |RST| every time isn't really necessary for
> |RST| source readability.
>
> .. |RST| replace:: reStructuredText
> .. _RST: http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html
> ```

Answer (score 1):

reStructuredText is a markup language to define static content. HTML content (I assumed the desired output format is HTML) is typically generated from reStructuredText on build time and then released/shipped to the user.

To allow users to specify variables, you would need a solution on top of reStructuredText, for example:

- Ship the content with a JavaScript plugin that dynamically replaces specific strings in the HTML document with user input.
- Generate the documentation on-the-fly after the user has specified the variables.

Note that these examples are not necessarily particularly viable solutions.